# WPF/XAML: Pass child component a variable value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Ok I find it weird that I cannot seem to find this anywhere. I come from an Angular environment where I could simply do

```
<my-component [someProperty]="someValue"></my-component>
```

where `someValue` is not the string 'someValue' but could be an object.

Now in WPF I am struggling to do something similar.

Suppose I have a control `child-control`  that needs a list of strings.

```
public partial class ChildControl: UserControl {
   public List<string> Names {get;set;}
}
```

I also have a control 'parent-control' where in the `ParentControl.xaml.cs` file the following list is declared

```
class ParentControl {
    public List<string> someList = new List<string>() { "A", "B" };
}
```

and I would now like to inject this list in the child control. So my `ParentControl.xaml` file looks like this

```
<UserControl
   ...>
    <child-control
      Names="someList"
    >
    </child-control>
</UserControl>
```

This throws an error.

> ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

So it inserts the string 'someList' instead of the object. I also tried stuff like

```
<child-control
  Names="{Binding someList}"
>
</child-control>
```

But this then throws the error

> A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.'

This seems like such a trivial thing to do. Yet I cannot find it anywhere. They either use built-in controls which is not my case or they do the weirdest stuff ever simply to pass a value to a control. [Some of this weird stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197906/wpf-passing-variables-from-parent-xaml-to-usercontrol) is to declare this variable twice as a dependency property in both child and parent component. How can it be that passing a variable is so cumbersome? There clearly must be a more elegant way.

Comment: maybe you should google MVVM and (Data)Binding

Answer (score 1):

The `Names` property must be defined as a [dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/collection-type-dependency-properties?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) for you to be able to bind something to it:

```
public partial class ChildControl : UserControl
{
    public ChildControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetValue(NamesProperty, new List<string>());
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NamesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
          name: nameof(Names),
          propertyType: typeof(List<string>),
          ownerType: typeof(ChildControl)
        );

    public List<string> Names
    {
        get => (List<string>)GetValue(NamesProperty);
        set => SetValue(NamesProperty, value);
    }
}
```

The XAML markup could then be defined something like this:

```
<UserControl Name="parent" ...>
    <local:ChildControl Names="{Binding someList, ElementName=parent}" />
</UserControl>
```

Also note that you can only bind to public *properties* so you also need to turn `someList` into a property (and consider changing its name to **S**omeList to comply with the naming guidelines):

```
public List<string> someList { get; } = new List<string>() { "A", "B" };
```